# Heroku "Couldn't find that process type"

Tags: python, heroku

Been trying to deploy my python selenium code to Heroku but I keep running into this issue:

--

Terminal command:

```
heroku ps:scale bot=1
```

Output:

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.2.
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (bot).
```

Procfile:

```
bot: python sfkafskafne.py
```

(Pycharm)

[image: Pycharm]

I'm deploying attempting to deploy to Heroku using the PyCharm terminal with the command above

Comment: Have you defined a `bot` process type? Please show us your `Procfile`.

Comment: @Chris Edited my post to include the Procfile

Comment: The contents of your `Procfile` look fine. That file must be (a) named `Procfile` _exactly_ (not `procfile`, `Procfile.txt`, or anything else) and (b) in the root directory of your project.

Comment: @Chris Well if thats the case than I'm quite confused on whats causing the issue. I edited my post again to show a screenshot of my project files maybe theres something wrong with it?

Comment: I can see a bit of another directory at the bottom of your screenshot. What is that?

Comment: @Chris Well heres a screenshot of all of them: [link](https://i.imgur.com/04V3dH9.png) (I believe there called folders) and those folders are inside of another folder named "pythonProjects"

Comment: Where is your repository root? The folder containing your `.git/` folder?

Comment: @Chris Well I couldn't find it in my pycharm files but I found it here: C:\Program Files\Git

Comment: That is probably the directory where Git is installed, not your project directory. How are you deploying to Heroku?

Comment: @Chris I'm deploying attempting to deploy to Heroku using the PyCharm terminal with the command in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm deploying attempting to deploy to Heroku using the PyCharm terminal with the command above

None of the commands in your post deploy your code. `heroku ps:scale` scales dynos *for code that has already been deployed*.

Before you scale your dynos, you need to get your code onto Heroku by deploying it. You can do so [via `git push`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), [GitHub integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration), or [Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime).

The first two options require that your code be committed to a Git repository. That's a good idea anyway, even if you choose to use Docker deployment.

For the first option, something like this should get you going:

- Change to the project directory with `cd INSTTTAAAAA`
- Create a Git repository with `git init`
- Commit your code with `git add .` followed by `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
- Add a remote with `heroku git:remote`
- Push your code with `git push heroku main`

Beyond this, I suggest you read the documentation I linke to above. There's lots more to learn that's beyond the scope of a SO question.

You will also want to push your code to GitHub or similar as well. Heroku is not meant to be your primary source code repository.

---

Side note: I'm not sure if `INSTTTAAAA` and `sfkafskafne` mean something in a language that you speak, but if these are effectively random I *strongly* urge you to rename them. Using good, clear names is very important.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242186/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-heroku-couldnt-find-that-process-type).